# Network not found error while changing Nodeport range in openshift origin using OC

Tags: deployment, openshift-origin

I am trying to change Nodeport range in openshift origin with below OC command
**oc patch network.config.openshift.io cluster --type=merge -p '{ "spec": { "serviceNodePortRange": "30000-" } }'**

I got the error like **network.config.openshift.io Not Found** am I missing any prerequisites.
Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the upper bound of the port range.

Try to run this:

```bash
oc patch network.config.openshift.io cluster \
    --type=merge \
    -p '{ "spec": { "serviceNodePortRange": "30000-33333" } }'
```

You should check the [Configuring the node port service range](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/networking/configuring-node-port-service-range.html#nw-nodeport-service-range-edit_configuring-node-port-service-range) page.